# Why can't malloc/free APIs be correctly called in threads created by clone?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, malloc

Why does some glibc's APIs(such as function `malloc()`, `realloc()` or `free()`) can not be correctly called in threads that are created by syscall clone?

Here is my code only for testing:

```
int thread_func( void *arg )
{
    void *ptr = malloc( 4096 );

    printf( "tid=%d, ptr=%x\n", gettid(), ptr );
    sleep(1);

    if( ptr )
        free( ptr );

    return 0;
}


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int i, m;
    void *stk;
    int stksz = 1024 * 128;
    int flag = CLONE_VM | CLONE _FILES | CLONE_FS | CLONE_SIGHAND;

    for( i=m=0; i < 100; i++ )
    {
        stk = malloc( stksz );

        if( !stk ) break;

        if( clone( thread_func, stk+stksz, flags, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL ) != -1 )
            m++;
    }

    printf( "create %d thread\n", m );
    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Testing result: thread `thread_func` or main thread `main` will be blocked on `malloc()` or `free()` function randomly. Or sometimes causes `malloc()` or `free()` to crash.

I think may be `malloc()` and `free()` need certain TLS data to distinguish every thread.

Does anyone know the reason, and what solution can been used to resolve this problem?

Comment: Any reason you're not using `pthread_create`?

Comment: You appear to have an off-by-one error in your `clone()` call.  The second argument should point to the top-most address in the child stack, but instead it points one byte *past* the top address of the allocated space.

Comment: We expect that when you present code that you claim exhibits a particular problem, that code in fact exhibits the problem described.  A prerequisite for that is the code **compiling at all**, which yours does not do on account of a stray space character and a name mismatch.  It also does not *link* on my Linux machine, on account of glibc not providing a wrapper function for the `gettid()` syscall.

Comment: In any case, because this question is Linux-specific, I have added the [linux] tag.  But [clone] does not refer to the Linux-specific `clone()` system call, so I have removed that tag.

Answer (score 2):

> I think may be malloc() and free() need certain TLS data to distinguish every thread.

Glibc's `malloc()` and `free()` do not rely on TLS.  They use mutexes to protect the shared memory-allocation data structures.  To reduce contention for those, they employ a strategy of maintaining separate memory-allocation arenas with independent metadata and mutexes.  This is documented on [their manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html#NOTES).

After correcting the syntax errors in your code and dummying-out the call to non-existent function `gettid()` (see comments on the question), I was able to produce segmentation faults, but not blockage.  Perhaps you confused the exit delay caused by your program's 10-second sleep with blockage.

In addition to any issue that may have been related to your undisclosed implementation of `gettid()`, your program contains two semantic errors, each producing undefined behavior:

1. As I already noted in comments, it passes the wrong child-stack pointer values.<sup>*</sup>
2. It uses the wrong `printf()` directive in `thread_func()` for printing the pointer.  The directive for pointer values is `%p`; `%x` is for arguments of type `unsigned int`.

After I corrected those errors as well, the program consistently ran to completion for me.  Revised code:

```
int thread_func(void *arg) {
    void *ptr = malloc(4096);

    // printf( "tid=%d, ptr=%x\n", gettid(), ptr );
    printf("tid=%d, ptr=%p\n", 1, ptr);
    sleep(1);

    if (ptr) {
        free(ptr);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i, m;
    char *stk;  // Note: char * instead of void * to afford arithmetic
    int stksz = 1024 * 128;
    int flags = CLONE_VM | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_FS | CLONE_SIGHAND;

    for (i = m = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        stk = malloc( stksz );

        if( !stk ) break;

        if (clone(thread_func, stk + stksz - 1, flags, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL ) != -1) {
            m++;
        }
    }

    printf("create %d thread\n", m);
    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Even with that, however, all is not completely well: I see various anomalies in the program output, especially near the beginning.

The bottom line is that, contrary to your assertion, ***you are not creating any threads***, at least not in the sense that the C library recognizes.  You are merely creating processes that have behavior similar to threads'.  That may be sufficient for some purposes, but you cannot rely on the system to treat such processes identically to threads.

On Linux, *bona fide* threads that the system and standard library will recognize are POSIX threads, launched via `pthread_create()`.  (I note here that modifying your program to use `pthread_create()` instead of `clone()` resolved the output anomalies for me.) You might be able to add flags and arguments to your `clone()` calls that make the resulting processes enough like the Linux implementation of pthreads to be effectively identical, but whyever would you do such a thing instead of just using real pthreads in the first place?

---

<sup>*</sup> The program also performs pointer arithmetic on a `void *`, which C does not permit.  GCC accepts that as an extension, however, and since your code is deeply Linux-specific anyway, I'm letting that slide with only this note.

Comment: for your comment, the function gettid() actually is macro likes "#define gettid()  syscall(SYS_gettid)", and the printf directive %x also is correct because the pointer 'ptr' is treated as a number(you can add case convert (unsigned long int)). And other hand, the top of stack is "address + size", it is not necessary to sub one byte, because the stack push always do two steps just like "ptr -= n;  *ptr = xxx"

Comment: @rockstone9527, the C standard specifies that "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined" ([C2011 7.21.6.1/9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9)).  That pointers can be *converted* to integers does not mean that values of those types are interchangeable.  No automatic conversions are performed on pointer values among the variable arguments of a varargs function such as `printf()`, so as I said, your program has undefined behavior.  And fixing that problem solved it segfaulting for me.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, `malloc` and `free` need TLS for at least the following things:

1. The malloc arena attached to the current thread (used for allocation operations).
2. The `errno` TLS variable (written to when system calls fail).
3. The stack protector canary (if enabled and the architecture stores the canary in the TCB).
4. The [malloc thread cache](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/02/malloc-internals-and-you/) (enabled by default in the upcoming glibc 2.26 release).

All these items need a properly initialized thread control block (TCB), but curiously, until recently and as far as `malloc`/`free` was concerned, it almost did not matter if a thread created with `clone` was shared with another TCB (so that the data is no longer thread-local):

Threads basically never reattach themselves to a different arena, so the arena TLS variable is practically read-only after initialization—and multiple threads can share a single arena.  `errno` can be shared as long as system calls only fail in one of the threads undergoing sharing.  The stack protector canary is read-only after process startup, and its value is identical across threads anyway.

But all this is an implementation detail, and things change radically in glibc 2.26 with its malloc thread cache: The cache is read and written without synchronization, so it is very likely that what you are trying to do results in memory corruption.

This is not a material change in glibc 2.26, it is always how things were: calling *any* glibc function from a thread created with `clone` is undefined.  [As John Bollinger pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285100/8316315), this mostly worked by accident before, but I can assure you that it has always been completely undefined.

Comment: I agree your comment, it is conflict between the linux-specific function clone  and the GLIBC functions. It seems only way of using pthread lib to resolve these problem. In fact, I'm not willing to employ pthread lib.

Comment: If you don't want to use libpthread, you cannot use multiple threads within the same address space which call *any* glibc function. The latter means that you have to block all signals in your custom threads, and use direct system calls (not the `syscall` function).